# firewalld inconsistent behaviour

Tags: docker, firewalld

I have a docker swarm with a number of nodes. They are connected through wireguard interfaces. All docker swarm communication happens inside the internal network, provided by wireguard. In the example below, the interface facing the internet is `eth0`, and the wireguard interface is called `intr`.

I added a socks5 proxy to a stack, looks like this in the compose file:

```yaml
services:
  proxy:
    hostname: proxy
    image: httptoolkit/docker-socks-tunnel
    ports:
      - 1080:1080/tcp
```

My goal is to restrict access to this service, so only clients on the intr network (e.g. originating the wireguard interface) are able to use it.

Here is a minimalistic set of commands that I used:

```bash
# replace ufw with firewalld
systemctl stop docker
systemctl stop ufw
apt remove --purge ufw
apt install -y firewalld
systemctl enable firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
systemctl start docker

# add eth0 to public zone, this will prevent all incoming connections, except ssh and ipv6-dhcp
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-interface=eth0
# allow 51830/udp (wireguard) so that the internal wireguard interfaces can connect on the nodes
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=51820/udp --permanent

# create a new zone for intr, add the intr interface to it
firewall-cmd --new-zone=intr --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=intr --add-interface=intr --permanent
# allow docker swarm ports on it
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=intr --add-service=docker-swarm --permanent

# create a policy that allows traffic between docker and intr interfaces
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy docker-intr --set-target=ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy docker-intr --add-ingress-zone intr
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy docker-intr --add-egress-zone docker

# change default policy of "docker" zone to drop
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --set-target=DROP

# for this example, allow socks5 on intr zone
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=intr --add-port=1080/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

After executing the above commands, it seems to be working. if I try to access it through wireguard, then the port is open:

```bash
nc -vz -w1 10.1.2.1 1080`
Connection to 10.1.2.1 1080 port [tcp/socks] succeeded!
```

If I try to access it on the public address, then it is dropped:

```bash
nc -vz -w1 my.server.com 1080`
Connection to my.server.com (1.2.3.4) port 1080 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

The same thing is true for port 2377/tcp (swarm): it seems to be open on the internal interface's address, but it is rejected on the public address

However, if I reboot the OS, then the following happens:

1. 2377/tcp (docker swarm) remains closed, even after docker starts up
2. 1080/tcp (socks) becomes open on all interfaces, including eth0 (after the socks service's container starts up)
3. but if I execute `firewall-cmd --reload` one minute later, then 1080/tcp becomes closed on eth0 again

I did not test this yet, but I suspect that if I bring down the docker stack, and bring it up again, then the same problem appears.

How is it possible, that according to the permanent firewalld settings, 1080/tcp should be closed, but is overwritten dynamically by docker? According to the official docs ( https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#integration-with-firewalld ), docker integrates seamlessly with firewalld.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried, and it is really inconsistent. If I do `docker stack rm test; docker stack deploy test` then the port opens up. If I do `firewalld-cmd --reload`, then it closes again. If I reboot the system, then it opens up again. In other words, it is useless, because the accessibility of the port depends on the last operation, and it cannot be predicted or planned.

Comment: BTW running `firewall-cmd --reload` wipes out all rules created by fail2ban, so I cannot use this even as a temporary solution.